# Firefox bookmarks that update as I surf

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Is there an extension or other method to enable special bookmarks that behave more like real-world bookmarks?

So, for example, I could bookmark the URL for section 1 of some multi-page online document.  Then if I opened that bookmark, clicked through to section 3 at a different URL, closed the tab, when I reopened the bookmark it would have automatically updated to to take me to section 3.

My computer isn't powerful enough to leave a lot of tabs open and just to rely on session restoring, but any other suggestions to enable this workflow would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, maybe not as automatic as you'd like it but it works for me: [Replace Bookmark](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bmreplace/)

Comment: Cheers, this looks useful.  I'll leave the question open a little longer to see if anyone has anything more automated, but this will do in a pinch.